# Plus Calcuation using Jquery in Contact form 7

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am trying to run plus calculation in contact form 7. Value of Field 1 & Field 2 should automatically show up as a sum in Field 3 on entering values in field 1 and field 2. (Field1 + Field2 = Field3) Any help on this? Below image will help you to know what exactly I am trying to do. Total Price is not appearing.

Here is the code

```
[checkbox checkbox-545 "BRW100"]
White Sandwich Loaf - Sliced  (df, yf, ef, ff)
900 gm
$8.95
[text text-695 id:qty placeholder "Enter QTY"]
[text text-792 id:price]


[checkbox checkbox-546 "BRS100"]
Seeded Sandwich Loaf - Sliced  (df, yf, ef, ff)
950 gm
$ 9.50 
[text text-696 id:qty1 placeholder "Enter QTY"]
[text text-793 id:price1]


<!--Total Price Calculation-->
[text text-903 id:items placeholder "Total Items"]
[text text-362 id:total "Total Price"]
</div>
```

I don't what to write for jquery.

[image]

Comment: Share the relevant HTML and JS. Screenshots don't work.

Comment: check now. I have updated.